# Second field in the bind() function for raw sockets in python

Tags: python, sockets

I am implementing a raw socket program in python and I came across `bind()` where I can bind my socket to the interface.  As I understand it, the first field for this function is the interface I wish to bind to.  **What is the second field?** Is this the Ethertype (such as IP4)?  In the [raw socket example](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/socket.html#example) found in the Python reference docs the code looks like this:

```
# create a raw socket and bind it to the public interface
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
s.bind((HOST, 0))
```

Why is the second field zero?  In other [examples](http://nullege.com/codes/search/socket.AF_PACKET) I have seen this is frequently set to 0x0800 (or 2048 in decimal) leading me to believe that this is possibly setting the socket to an IP4 protocol.  I have also seen this set to 9999. Perhaps I am missing/misunderstanding something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second field indicates the port number you are binding to. Set it to 0 however, will let  the OS pick an available port for you from range 1024 to 65535.

You can then get the port that was chosen by `sock.getsockname()[1]`.

Also, setting the first field (host) to `0.0.0.0` or `''` will allow accepting connections from any IPv4 address.

---

Edit: As @highlycaffeinated pointed out, the above is true because `socket.AF_INET` address family is chosen. If however, [socket.AF_INET6](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.AF_INET6) is chosen, the format will be `(host, port, flowinfo, scopeid)`.

Comment: +1. It's worth mentioning that this has nothing to do with raw sockets; the exact same thing is true for stream or datagram (TCP or UDP, for the INET family).

Answer (score 1):

The value depends on the address family you are using.  For `AF_INET` like you show, its the port number.  From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html):

> Socket addresses are represented as follows: A single string is used
>   for the AF_UNIX address family. A pair (host, port) is used for the
>   AF_INET address family, where host is a string representing either a
>   hostname in Internet domain notation like 'daring.cwi.nl' or an IPv4
>   address like '100.50.200.5', and port is an integer. For AF_INET6
>   address family, a four-tuple (host, port, flowinfo, scopeid) is used,
>   where flowinfo and scopeid represents sin6_flowinfo and sin6_scope_id
>   member in struct sockaddr_in6 in C. For socket module methods,
>   flowinfo and scopeid can be omitted just for backward compatibility.
>   Note, however, omission of scopeid can cause problems in manipulating
>   scoped IPv6 addresses. Other address families are currently not
>   supported.

Comment: This is all correct, but it doesn't explain the special meaning of port 0, which is what probably confused the OP.